# Getting error: unsupported_grant_type using httpclient to post formdata in asp.net console app

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpclient

I have searched all over SO all to no avail, still have no solution. 
I'm trying to get auth token from an third party service using asp.net console app and httpclient. 
Everything works in Postman but replicating same in c# returns `"{\"error\":\"unsupported_grant_type\"}"`

Here's my code

```
 using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

                var multiform = new MultipartFormDataContent()
                {
                    {new StringContent("password"), "grant_type" },
                    {new StringContent("adfadsasdfas"), "username" },
                    {new StringContent("asdfasdadf"), "password" },
                };

                var response = Task.Run(() => httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:61216/token", multiform)).Result;

                var message = Task.Run(() => response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).Result;

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    throw new HttpRequestException("Unable to post to cliams manager");
                }

            }
```

Thanks in anticipation...
Sorry I have updated the grant_type to password. It's actually not the grant_type because "password" also didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Because you are setting the incorrect grant_type

Comment: Hard to know why. But if this can help you, there is a way to generate code using Postman. If you click the Code button (on the right under the "Save"

Comment: same grant_type works on postman, grant_type is not real value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue seems to be with this part of the code:

```
var multiform = new MultipartFormDataContent()
                {
                    {new StringContent("password"), "grant_type" },
                    {new StringContent("adfadsasdfas"), "username" },
                    {new StringContent("asdfasdadf"), "password" },
                };
```

You should be using this instead:

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>[] {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "asdfsad"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "asdfaasdfa")
   }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In OAuth 2 we set the `grant_type` to "password" when we send user id and password to retrieve the access token and also you are sending the data in incorrect format You have specified the Content-type to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but you are sending `multipart/form-data` in the `POST`.

You can read more about Password Grant type here
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2

Comment: Have edited the Question, grant_type = "password" didn't also work at first try